# How can I know what is the executed query in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

In my Android application, I update a row :

```
        int result = db.update(TABLE_TIENDA, values, TIENDA_ID + " = ? AND "+ TIENDA_PROYECTO_ID + " = ? ",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(tienda.getId()), String.valueOf(tienda.getProyecto().proyectoid) });
```

This query update 2 rows when it should update only 1. I would like to see the query it executes to confirm what's wrong.
Is it posible to have a log or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Well the easy answer is that if you want to see the actual query, use rawQuery and send a SQL command rather than use those helper functions.  They were meant for novices who are scared of writing real SQL, they're just going to write the query for you.

As for what this query will send-  its not going to do anything tricky.  Its basically just going to stick the parameters together:  UPDATE TABLE_TIENDA SET values_key0=values_value0, values_key1=values_value1... WHERE TIENDA_ID  = ? AND  TIENDA_PROYECTO_ID  ?;

Answer (score 0):

You can set the error logging level with adb

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.SQLiteLog V
adb shell setprop log.tag.SQLiteStatements V
```

then restart it

```
adb shell stop
adb shell start
```

This will allow you to see the executed queries in logcat